# Why does this function return different results?

Tags: python, list

Can someone explain to me why this function returns different results:

```
def g(x, z):
  x.append(z)
  return x

y = [1, 2, 3]
g(y, 4).extend(g(y[:], 4))

y = [1, 2, 3]
g(y[:], 4).extend(g(y, 4))
```

The first returns

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

and the second

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Both return `None`, actually. You mean that `y` is set to that value afterwards?

Comment: Why are you going to such lengths to make Python list manipulations so convoluted?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, `None` is returned, because `list.extend()` extends the list *in-place*. So you must be looking at what `y` ends up as. And that's where the rub is; you didn't extend `y` itself in the second example.

In the first example, you essentially do this:

```
y.append(4)          # y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temp_copy = y[:]     # temp_copy = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temp_copy.append(4)  # temp_copy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
y.extend(temp_copy)  # y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
del temp_copy
print(y)
```

The `temp_copy` name is never really created; the list is only available on the stack and briefly as `x` inside `g()`, which is why I delete `temp_copy` again at the end to make this clear.

So `y` is first appended to, then extended with another list (which happens to be a copy of `y` with another element added).

In your second example, you do this instead:

```
temp_copy = y[:]    # temp_copy = [1, 2, 3]
temp_copy.append(4) # temp_copy = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y.append(4)         # y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temp_copy.extend(y) # temp_copy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
del temp_copy
print(y)
```

You appended one element to `y`, and all other manipulations apply to a copy. The copy is *discarded* again, because in your code there is no reference to it.

Comment: Ahh I understand now, thankyou so much for the detailed response

Answer (score 0):

You made kind of a mess with assignments and copies there. Note that:

- `append()` modifies the list in-place, without creating a new one
- so does `extend()`
- `y[:]` does create a new list

Your expressions return `None`. You only effect modifications to the lists, you don't save references to new ones.

Let me "unroll" your code, to show the difference:

```
# First snippet:
y = [1, 2, 3]
y.append(4)
y_copy = list(y)
y_copy.append(4)
y.extend(y_copy)

# Second snippet:
y = [1, 2, 3]
y_copy = list(y)
y_copy.append(4)
y.append(4)
y_copy.extend(y)
```

As you can see, in the second example, you apply most modifications to the *copy*, not the original. In the first, all changes go to the original.

On a subjective note, that code piece was very hard to understand. You wrote it yourself and couldn't follow it, and I have years of experience in Python and still had to pull the "unrolling" trick. Try to keep your code simpler, so that objects can be followed and reasoned about.

Answer (score -1):

On the first call you pass the list by reference, on the second call you made a copy of the list(sublisting it).
explain :

```
>>> one = [1,2,3]
>>> ref = one 
>>> copy = one[:]
>>> one 
[3, 2, 3]  
>>> ref
[3, 2, 3]  
>>> copy
[1, 2, 3]
```